# Error in c program when compiling on arm platform

Tags: c

Compiling simple c program on arm platform.

```
typedef struct
{
    char* Case;
    int  RespCmdLen;
    unsigned char *RespCommand;

}ResponseStruct;
int main()
{
    unsigned char CommandResp[] = { 
        0x01,
        0x08, 0x07,
        0x05, 0x00,
        0x00,
        0x00,
        0x0B,
        0x00,
        0x00,
    };
    ResponseStruct CaseRespTbl[] =
    {
         /* case,           Response length,                response buffer pointer   */
         { "case1",             sizeof(CommandResp),        CommandResp},
    };

    return 0;
}
```

and got error like

```
Error:  #24: expression must have a constant value
         { "case1",             sizeof(CommandResp),        CommandResp},
                                                            ^
```

But if i change that code to

```
ResponseStruct CaseRespTbl[10];
CaseRespTbl[0].Case = "case1";
CaseRespTbl[0].RespCmdLen = sizeof(CommandResp);
CaseRespTbl[0].RespCommand = CommandResp;
```

Then it will compiled without any issue.

Any reason for that?

Comment: Non-constant initialisers are a C99 thing - you haven't said which compilers you're using and how you're compiling on each, but I suspect once you have that information you'll also have the answer ;)

Comment: I am using ARM RVCT 3.1 toochain

Comment: RVCT [assumes C90 unless you tell it otherwise](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.kui0098a/armccref_chdjhdbj.htm) - I guess you're not telling it otherwise?

Comment: You could move the variables to global scope; they look pretty global + constant to me.

Comment: @joop that wouldn't help either. also, why globals? like, at all?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant :  Global because it *looks like* a lookup table; it could be needed allover the program. But it could be also declared static or function static (in main()), too. This would also save some initialisation of automatic variables. And size. BTW: it works here.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the command response is constant, I would simply ditch it and use:

```
ResponseStruct CaseRespTbl[] = {
    #  Case    Sz   Bytes
    { "case1", 10, "\x01\x08\x07\x05\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x00" },
};
```

You can still *use* `sizeof` if you want, by putting that final string into a `#define`, something like:

```
#define CMD_RESP "\x01\x08\x07\x05\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x00"
ResponseStruct CaseRespTbl[] = {
    #  Case    Sz                  Bytes
    { "case1", sizeof(CMD_RESP)-1, CMD_RESP },
};
```

but that's probably not necessary for data that doesn't change very often.